# How to retrieve the real redirect location header with Curl? without using {redirect_url}

Tags: bash, redirect, curl

I realized that Curl {redirect_url} does not always show the same redirect URL. For example if the URL header is`Location: https:/\example.com` this will redirect to `https:/\example.com` but curl {redirect_url} shows `redirect_url: https://host-domain.com/https:/\example.com` and it won't display the response real location header. (I like to see the real `location:` result.)

This is the BASH I'm working with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: urls-checker.sh domains.txt
FILE="$1"
while read -r LINE; do
     # read the response to a variable
     response=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -s -k --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$LINE")
     # get the title
     title=$(sed -n 's/.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*/\1/ip;T;q'<<<"$response")
     # read the write-out from the last line
     read -r http_code size_header redirect_url < <(tail -n 1 <<<"$response")
     printf "***Url: %s\n\n" "$LINE"
     printf "Status: %s\n\n" "$http_code"
     printf "Size: %s\n\n" "$size_header"
     printf "Redirect-url: %s\n\n" "$redirect_url"
     printf "Title: %s\n\n" "$title"
     # -c 20 only shows the 20 first chars from response
     printf "Body: %s\n\n" "$(head -c 100 <<<"$response")"
done < "${FILE}"
```

How can I `printf "Redirect-url:` the original requested `location: header` without having to use `redirect_url`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To read the exact `Location` header field value, as returned by the server, you can use the [`-i`/`--include`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-i) option, in combination with `grep`.

For example:

```
$ curl 'http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http:/\example.com' -si | grep -oP 'Location: \K.*'
http:/\example.com
```

Or, if you want to read all **headers**, **content** and the **`--write-out` variables** line (according to your script):

```
response=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -s -i -k --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$url")

# break the response in parts
headers=$(sed -n '1,/^\r$/p' <<<"$response")
content=$(sed -e '1,/^\r$/d' -e '$d' <<<"$response")
read -r http_code size_header redirect_url < <(tail -n1 <<<"$response")

# get the real Location
location=$(grep -oP 'Location: \K.*' <<<"$headers")
```

---

Fully integrated in your script, this looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: urls-checker.sh domains.txt
file="$1"
while read -r url; do
    # read the response to a variable
    response=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -s -i -k --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$url")

    # break the response in parts
    headers=$(sed -n '1,/^\r$/p' <<<"$response")
    content=$(sed -e '1,/^\r$/d' -e '$d' <<<"$response")
    read -r http_code size_header redirect_url < <(tail -n1 <<<"$response")

    # get the real Location
    location=$(grep -oP 'Location: \K.*' <<<"$headers")

    # get the title
    title=$(sed -n 's/.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*/\1/ip;T;q'<<<"$content")

    printf "***Url: %s\n\n" "$url"
    printf "Status: %s\n\n" "$http_code"
    printf "Size: %s\n\n" "$size_header"
    printf "Redirect-url: %s\n\n" "$location"
    printf "Title: %s\n\n" "$title"
    printf "Body: %s\n\n" "$(head -c 100 <<<"$content")"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Cool! Yes that is perfect. How can I integrate this into my code to display `Redirect-url: http:/\example.com`? if you can help me with that it be great

Comment: Thanks yes it looks good but did I add it correctly to the code? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/60550f0ba3a7bf814f879da59bdb13f1

Comment: Looks good, just make sure you use the new variable `location`, instead of (or in addition to) `redirect_url`. Also, for body you can use `content`.

Comment: Can you please update the code for me? That would be if much help.

Comment: This should do it, please have a look.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot @randomir!

Answer (score 4):

According to @randomir answer and since I was only need raw redirect URL I use this command on my  batch

```
 curl  -w "%{redirect_url}" -o /dev/null -s "https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507336/3019002"
```

Answer (score 0):

`https:/\example.com` is not a legal URL(*). The fact that this works in browsers in an abomination (that I've fought against) and curl doesn't. `%{redirect_url}` shows exactly the URL curl would redirect to...

A URL should use to forward slashes, so the above should look like `http://example.com`.

(*) = I refuse to accept the WHATWG "definition".

Comment: I agree URL `https:/\example.com` is not valid URL but this is just an example. I need the real location header for debugging.

Comment: I'm only looking to get the real result. Curl request does show `Location: https:/\example.com` and I like to see this as `Redirect-url: https:/\example.com` on my result

Comment: I understand that.  I'm not looking to be redirected.

Comment: You can test with this `curl -v -w "redirect_url: %{redirect_url}\n" -o /dev/null -s "https://app-1495017961.000webhostapp.com/redirect.php?url=https:/\example.com"`

Comment: Since the redirect is using a broken URL, that won't work with URL parsers that are just the slightest more strict than your browser.

Comment: I understand where you coming from but `h‌ttps:/\example.com` is just an example to show the behavior. I need to get the `Location:` that curl is showing

Comment: just use `-i` (or perhaps `-I`) and grep the output?

Comment: Yes, something like that may work but I'm not sure how to integrate this into the code.